# MSGARCH fitting doesn't work for the specific part of the data

Tags: r, garch, fitting, moving-window, error-message

I'm trying to do rolling (expanding) window forecast with MSGARCH and the model is failing for very specific $i$. For example I get error for $i=14$ and $i=30$. Data is snp500 returns data between 2010 and 2021.

```
spec <- CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("sGARCH","gjrGARCH")),
distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("std","std")),
switch.spec = list(do.mix = FALSE))

test_size <- 365

for (i in 0:365)
{
    fit <- FitML(spec = spec, data = snp[0:(length(snp)-(test_size -i))])
}
```

Error I get is

```
Error in stats::optim(par = vPw_mod, fn = f_nll, data = data, spec = spec, : non-finite value supplied by optim
Traceback:

1. FitML(spec = spec, data = snp[0:(length(snp) - (test_size - i))])
2. FitML.MSGARCH_SPEC(spec = spec, data = snp[0:(length(snp) - (test_size - 
 .     i))])
3. f_InferenceFun(vPww, data_, spec, do.plm = ctr$do.plm)
4. stats::optim(par = vPw_mod, fn = f_nll, data = data, spec = spec, 
 .     do.plm = do.plm, method = "BFGS", control = list(maxit = 1L), 
 .     hessian = TRUE)
```

Data doesn't contain NaN values and actually fits normally when using in total. Fitting fails when I use all but some small number of last points. Any clues on what might be wrong?

Comment: What library are you using? And since you are using S&P500 which can be downloaded easily from within R, you could make this into a reproducible example by adding just a few lines.

Comment: I'm using MSGARCH. I have tried briefly to use snp with this package but somehow it produced format-like errors.